# For loop with error in code

Tags: java, loops, random

UPDATE****

I have my program compiling and executing correctly but now I have faced another problem. I need to create variables that will count each time a certain random number is generated. For example `count0` is supposed to record how many times the integer `0` is generated. This is what I have:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class L10{
public static void main(String[] args){
int total = 100;

Random randObj = new Random();

final int UPPER_BOUND = 10;


for (int i=0; i < total; i++){
int randomInt = randObj.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND);

System.out.print("\n" + randomInt);


int count0 = 0;
if(randomInt==0){

System.out.print(randomInt + count0);
}
int count1 = 1;
if(randomInt==1){

}
int count2 = 2;
int count3 = 3;
int count4 = 4;
int count5 = 5;
int count6 = 6;
int count7 = 7;
int count8 = 8;
int count9 = 9;
}



}
}
```

The output shows the random number, in this case zero, and prints a zero next to it. I'm not exactly sure how to write code that keeps track of how many times zero is generated. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at any example of using `new Random` and compare it to what you have. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: `Random randObj = new Random();` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
    Random randObj = new Random();

    final int UPPER_BOUND = 10;
    int total = 100;
    String star = "*";

        for (int i=0; i < UPPER_BOUND; i++){
            int randomInt = randObj.nextInt(total);
            System.out.print(randomInt);
        }
    }
}
```

Modifications:

`Random randObj = new Random();`

`int randomInt = randObj.nextInt(total);`

Comment: thank you that helped out, check my updated question. I need to produce 100 random numbers between 0-10 not 10 random numbers between 0-100

Comment: never mind i just got it, will be reporting back with more questions tomorrow though @JunM

Comment: @Himz Glad you have it figured out. I'm not a java coder though :D It's obvious that your loop needs to range to `100` to generate 100 numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your intention is to generate 100 random integers in the range 0-9, and count the frequency of each.

Using separate variables for each count is a poor idea. A better idea is to use a single *array* of size 10, whose index is the random number.

Modifying your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    final int TOTAL = 100, UPPER_BOUND = 10;
    Random randObj = new Random();
    int[] count = new int[UPPER_BOUND];
    // collect frequencies
    for (int i=0; i < TOTAL; i++)
        count[randObj.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND)]++;
    // report frequencies
    for (int i=0; i < UPPER_BOUND; i++)
        System.out.print(i + "'s frequency was " + count[i];
}
```

Comment: I would exactly do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class L10{
public static void main(String[] args){
int total = 100;
int[] CountArray = new int[total];    //count numbers    
Random randObj = new Random();    
final int UPPER_BOUND = 10;   

for (int i=0; i < total; i++){
int randomInt = randObj.nextInt(UPPER_BOUND);

System.out.print("\n" + randomInt);

switch(randomInt){
    case(0):{
       CountArray[0]++;
       break;
    }
    case(1):{
       CountArray[1]++;
       break;
    }
    case(2):{
       CountArray[2]++;
       break;
    }
    case(3):{
       CountArray[3]++;
       break;
    }
    case(4):{
       CountArray[4]++;
       break;
    }
    case(5):{
       CountArray[5]++;
       break;
    }
    case(6):{
       CountArray[6]++;
       break;
    }
    case(7):{
       CountArray[7]++;
       break;
    }
    case(8):{
       CountArray[8]++;
       break;
    }
    case(9):{
       CountArray[9]++;
       break;
    }
}
}
    System.out.println("");
for(int j = 0;j<UPPER_BOUND;j++){
    System.out.println("number of "+ j+" generated "+CountArray[j]);
}
}
}
```

This is the Code that I came up with. I used an array to count each element and used switch case to count them separately. so at the end of the for loop. I printed them. This way you can get the number of elements distinctively.

Comment: Doing this can be quite bad, even though it might work. What if OP wants to generate 1 million random numbers? Write 1 million switch statements?

Comment: In that case true. But the question seems to do the same thing?

Comment: It looks pretty hard-coded and any **minor** changes in the requirement will result in **major** changes in your codes.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing `()` after `new Random`.

Comment: I comment with a helpful correction to a simple mistake in the code, and it gets down-voted?? No good deed goes unpunished.